# how to add custom block at onepage checkout discount codes below?

Tags: magento2

I want to add custom block below discount codes.But no idea how to add?

because m2 using knockout.js and some new concepts like passing arguments to block in layout files.its totally confusing.

Comment: have you done this?

Comment: @magentotwo have you done this in checkout page ?

Comment: @NewBeeInMagento No.

Comment: @magentotwo I want to do like this > http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159346/magento-2-add-custom-extesion-html-file-in-shipping-method-block

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you know how to creat module in `M2`

First of all go to

`\app\code\YOUR_NAME_SPACE\YOUR_MODULE_NAME\view\frontend\layout`

create new `xml` while with the name of  `checkout_cart_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">   
    <body>        
        <referenceContainer name="content">  
            <block class="YOUR_NAME_SPACE\YOUR_MODULE_NAME\Block\Cart" name="custom-cart" template="cart.phtml" after="checkout.cart.coupon" />
        </referenceContainer>        
    </body>
</page>
```

create new `cart.phtml` file in below path

`app\code\YOUR_NAME_SPACE\YOUR_MODULE_NAME\view\frontend\templates\`

```
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

It will print Hello World below discount section.

Comment: i need in checkout page below discount codes

Comment: I need in checkout page not in cart page.please read once again.

Comment: i also need in checkout page below discount codes