# Magento 2 add custom data to shipping method

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, additional-information

Hello I'm trying to add custom data to shipping method (image url, to be exact). Following [this example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159346/magento-2-add-custom-extesion-html-file-in-shipping-method-block/159632#159632) I managed to add extension attribute to interface and show field named 'image' in extension attributes (in JSON view). So now I'm stuck on **how to populate that extension attribute when creating method.**

For example I would need to do something like this:

```
    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
    $method->setCarrier($carrier);
    $method->setCarrierTitle($carrier_title);
    $method->setMethod($carrier_method);
    $method->setMethodTitle($carrier_method_title);
    $method->setPrice($price);
    $method->setCost($price);
    $method->setData('image','https://someurl.com.image.jpg');
    $result->append($method);
```

The problem is in this line:

```
$method->setData('image','https://someurl.com.image.jpg');
// I also tried using this
$method->setImage('https://someurl.com.image.jpg');
```

But either way I can't get that because it doesn't exist when I list all data from shipping method in front controller. I tried using:

```
$result->getData('image');
// I also tried
$result->getImage('image');
```

And when I try:

```
$result->getExtensionAttributes();
```

it returns null.

Could you please help me how set some data when creating method and pass it to extension attribute.

Comment: try using $method->addData() instead of $method->setData()

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. addData requires array and once array is passed it doesn't show it using getData().

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy to pass data as extension attribute. Please refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/34202497/2536631

Comment: Thank you for this link, but in the end I've solved it using Magento Registry since that data doesn't need to be stored anyway, just displayed at frontend.

Comment: how can you solve this? please let me know.