# Add custom dropdown after shipping in checkout and generate options by API call

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, soap-api-v2

I have to add one dropdown field after shipping methods on checkout page and populate options by API call result.

To add field i am referring below link and i am able to display dropdown after shipping methods but not understanding where to call that API and how to pass dynamic options to dropdown.

[Magento 2 add custom extesion html file in shipping method block](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159346/magento-2-add-custom-extesion-html-file-in-shipping-method-block)

In view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="iqmetrix-store" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Module/js/view/checkout/shipping/iqmetrix-store</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

In view\frontend\web\js\view\checkout\shipping\view\frontend\web\js\view\checkout\shipping.js

```
define([
'uiComponent'

], function (Component) {
'use strict';

return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Evdpl_Iqmatrix/checkout/shipping/iqmetrix-store'
    }
});
});
```

In view\frontend\web\template\checkout\shipping\iqmetrix-store.html

```
<div class="iqmetrix-store-sec">
<div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Select iQmetrix Store'" data-role="title"></div>
<div class="iqmetrix-block" id="iqmetrix-block">
   <select name="rqstore" class="validate-select">
              <option value="">Select iQmetrix Store</option>
              <option value="">iQmetrix - Davidson</option>
              <option value="">iQmetrix - Vancouver</option>
   </select>
</div>
</div>
```

I have to display this select dropdown on checkout only if logged in customer have some data in custom fields in backend and i have to populate this options by API.

Please provide me some solution.

Comment: specify the code which you try, Not the refrence link.

Comment: I have added code.